# Implement case class inside a class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, qubole

I am using the below code to run in Qubole Notebook and the code is running successfully.

```
case class cls_Sch(Id:String, Name:String)
class myClass { 
    implicit val sparkSession = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
    sparkSession.sql("set spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled = true")
    sparkSession.sql("set spark.sql.caseSensitive=false")   
    import sparkSession.sqlContext.implicits._
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path, LocatedFileStatus, RemoteIterator, FileUtil}
    import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration 
    import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

    def my_Methd() {                

        var my_df = Seq(("1","Sarath"),("2","Amal")).toDF("Id","Name")      

        my_df.as[cls_Sch].take(my_df.count.toInt).foreach(t => {            

            println(s"${t.Name}")

        })              
    }
}
val obj_myClass = new myClass()
obj_myClass.my_Methd()
```

[image]

However when I run in the same code in Qubole's Analyze, I am getting the below error.

[image]

When I take out the below code, its running fine in Qubole's Anlayze.

```
my_df.as[cls_Sch].take(my_df.count.toInt).foreach(t => {            

            println(s"${t.Name}")

        })
```

I believe somewhere I have to change the usage of `case` class.

I am using Spark 2.3.

Can someone please let me know how to solve this issue.

Please let me know if you need any other details.

Comment: try to put: import sparkSession.implicits._

Comment: You mean to say "sparkSession.implicits._" instead of "sparkSession.sqlContext.implicits._"? @EmiCareOfCell44

Comment: Yes, the error says that the product encoders(case classes) are available in that package

Comment: I tried that way also. Its throwing the same error @EmiCareOfCell44

Answer (score 1):

For any reason the kernel finds problems when working with dataset. I made two tests that worked with Apache Toree:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Emi. I will check this and let you know tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is have the `import spark.implicits._` inside the my_Methd() function.

```
def my_Methd() {   

    import spark.implicits._     

    var my_df = Seq(("1","Sarath"),("2","Amal")).toDF("Id","Name")      

    my_df.as[cls_Sch].take(my_df.count.toInt).foreach(t => {            

        println(s"${t.Name}")

    })              
}
```